# yii2 gridview,js not loading on page

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am loading a gridview

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new ReconReportSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'company_list' => $companyList
    ]);
}
```

And in the view

```
use yii\grid\GridView;
    echo GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'recon_reports',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'accounting_year','accounting_month'
        ],
    ]);
```

My model and searchmodel has the field rule as 'safe'

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use app\models\ReconReport;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

/**
 * Class ReconReportSearch
 * @package app\models
 */
class ReconReportSearch extends ReconReport
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['accounting_year','accounting_month'],'safe']
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @param $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {

        if ($this->load($params) && $this->validate()) {
            $this->_filtered = true;
        }
        $query = ReconReport::find()->with('company');

        // add conditions that should always apply here
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'accounting_year', $this->accounting_year]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'accounting_month', $this->accounting_month]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

The filter is failing to submit.
I tracked this down to the gridview.js not loading.

As a result, there is no query being launched. The action is not called again, with or without Pjax (I wait on the action in the debugger and it also reaches on the page load. Additionally, the NW tab on the browser dev toolbar does not show the action being called again.

A second project filters properly because the  gridview.js is loaded on the page. There is nothing extra in both projects to add or configure gridview.

I also tried manually adding the gridview js. Firstly this does not solve the problem of the search not being fired. However, I notice the .js file is listed twice, compared to zero times when I do not manually add the .js file.

What am I doing wrong? and how can I add gridview on the page?

Comment: Have you tried `Yii::debug($dataProvider->query->all());` to see if your query gives the desired result? If not, show us the `ReconReportSearch::search()`code.

Comment: @WeSee I have added the code and also added more information about the (not) firing of the search action.

Comment: Is the return at the end reached? Why do you load() twice?   Why do you validate() if there are no rules (e.g. number)?

Comment: @WeSee when I type the search result, the search is not fired at all. This is the issue. The actionSearch() is the controller is not fired after search. I at least need to get the search to run - the issue is not with the search results. (I have cleaned up the extra load and validate, BTW)

Comment: Are there Js errors in your browser console? This gets handled by Yii & GridVview. You do not have to care about.

Comment: No JS errors. For now I have a workaround. I added code  <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
 and removed 'filterModel' => $searchModel,.

Comment: Try to add accounting_year and accounting_month as public properties and make an array_merge with the parent::rules().